# bigvideo.js possible to use youtube video?

Tags: jquery, video, youtube

I just started using bigvideo.js

I am wondering if it is possible to use a youtube video or is there a js plugin that will allow me to use a youtube video full screen on an element only...here is my code:

```
$(function() {
                var BV = new $.BigVideo({container: $('#header')});
                BV.init();
                BV.show('https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID');
        });
```

Comment: You will likely need to download the .mp4 from youtube and use that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [closed issue](https://github.com/dfcb/BigVideo.js/issues/9) on the BigVideo github where it is indicated by the creator of BigVideo this is not possible:

> BigVideo requires a direct link to the mp4, not an embed code. If you want to use YouTube, try Tubular http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/